How to force android studio to use proguard instead of r8?
I'm trying to use zelix klassmaster for my Android project, and it has a feature to translate proguard into their own obfuscation technique. I know that android studio uses r8 by default, i wanted to know how to make it disable r8 and use proguard instead.

Check if adding android.enableR8=false in gradle.properties works for you.

Built-in ProGuard support was removed from AGP some time ago. However, GuardSquare are shipping a Gradle Plugin, see https://www.guardsquare.com/manual/setup/gradleplugin.
